# What does it mean when someone says "Let's Talk Consistency"

Tags: american-english

What does it mean when someone says, **"Let's Talk Consistency"** Does it mean **talk in harmony**? I've just spotted that and would like to learn it and implement it in my day to day vocabulary. I will appreciate if some examples are given. I already checked a few dictionaries to no avail.

Comment: Please give some context. This sounds like the speaker feels that consistency is in some manner being overlooked or mis-defined or misapplied. Possible scenario: A says "candidate X is a poor choice, he has made inconsistent decisions" B says, "well lets talk consistency, your candidate has done ... and ... and ... is that consistent?"

Answer (score 5):

When someone says "Let's talk___," it means they are suggesting beginning a conversation on the topic of "___"

Consistency can mean a few things, but most likely in this case it means to keep something consistent, as in keeping it the same over time.

For example, if I have just started a new job asa web designer, my boss, while telling me about my job description may say "Let's talk consistency" to introduce the topic of keeping web pages with consistence fonts and sizes.

The exact phrase you gave has been present in many online articles, because it seems to be a common way to title one of such a topic, but I have never heard someone actually say it in real conversation.